# React-Native, shared state between components (react-native-router-flux)

Tags: react-native

I'm building a React-Native app, where all the data is based on socket data.
All of my components (tabs) needs to have essentailly the same state, as 1 data change could affect multiple components.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the redux for managing the state.

https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: I dont want to get into hooks where you cant use classes.